# Error con validaciones del modelo en ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net, mvc, validación, controller, model

Tengo validando un formulario de ingreso de clientes, con tag helpers. En mi controlador (GET) hago llamado a una APi para obtener las categorías de los clientes, lo almaceno en ViewBag y luego lo muestro en la vista. El problema se presenta cuando el estado del modelo no es valido y retorno la vista, me da un error porque no hay referencia a la instancia de objeto de las categorías. Quisiera saber si hay alguna solución para este caso o sería mejor que hiciese la validación con JavaScript.

[image: Formulario][image: Controlador]

[image: Error]

Comment: Primero decirte que todo lo que es codigo es mejor escrivirlo para que podamos hacer pruebas @noob0805. Por otro lado cuando haces el post por lo que estoi viendo no recargar el **ViewBag** tienes que volverlo a cargar para que al renderizar la vista se cargue el combo con las categorias.

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario. Cuando el estado del modelo no es valido, retorna a la vista y es cuando se produce la excepción porque el ViewBab.Categories se inicializa en el controlador, no en la vista. Pareciera que la solución sería retornar al método get del controlador pero no aparecerían los errores en los campos del formulario..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que no me entendiste bien... en el método Get haces lo siguiente.

```
//GET Method
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(){
   var categorias = await _customerCatRepository.GetAllAsync();
   ViewBag.Categories = categorias;
   return View();
}
```

Esto lo que haces es que cuando llamas a la vista en GET te carga las categorías lo pones en el **ViewBag** y devuelves la vista. Después en la vista automáticamente lo carga tal como la tienes montada. Hasta aquí esta bien, pero en el metodo POST lo que te digo es que hagas lo siguiente:

```
//POST: Method
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(CusomerCreatemodel customer){
   if(!create.success){
     var categorias = await _customerCatRepository.GetAllAsync();
     ViewBag.Categories = categorias;
     return View();
   }
}
```

De esta manera cuando vuelves a la vista que es lo que le estas haciendo cuando tienes el success a false, devuelves el ViewBag cargado. Consejo yo lo que hago es crearme una función con todos los ViewBag que cargo en esa vista así tanto en el GET como en el POST solamente llamo a dicha función para que me cargue los viewbags y me despreocupo de lo demás.